# Ayuda con filtros en sql server

Tags: sql-server

Necesito ayuda en un problema con un código en *SQL Server*. A ver que soluciones me pueden dar:

Lo que quiero es lo siguiente:

```
select  me.cNombreMedio, COUNT(relmei.lIdtplEncuestaMedio),CONVERT(NUMERIC(12,4),(COUNT(relmei.lIdtplEncuestaMedio)/CONVERT(NUMERIC(12,4),(SELECT count(*) FROM tencuesta WHERE lidtplPregunta = 1 and lidtplTipoSexo = 1))*100))
from tRelEncuestaMedio as relmei
inner join tMedio as me on relmei.lIdtplMedio = me.lIdtplMedio
GROUP BY cNombreMedio
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se buscó en la segunda columna. Un filtro donde pueda ver la multiplicación en esa columna y tipo sexo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: queres agrupar por sexo tambien? me parece que estas preguntado eso (de una forma poco ortodoxa). Y ya tenes multiples filtros en una tabla, cuando pones mas de una cosa en el where.

Comment: Este es el codigo:

select  me.cNombreMedio , COUNT(relmei.lIdtplEncuestaMedio),CONVERT(NUMERIC(12,4),(COUNT(relmei.lIdtplEncuestaMedio)/CONVERT(NUMERIC(12,4),(SELECT count(*) FROM tencuesta WHERE lidtplPregunta = 1 and lidtplTipoSexo = 1))*100))
from tRelEncuestaMedio as relmei where lIdtplTipoSexo = 1
inner join tMedio as me on relmei.lIdtplMedio = me.lIdtplMedio
inner join tEncuesta as ma on relmei.lIdtplEncuesta = ma.lIdtplEncuesta
GROUP BY cNombreMedio

Puedo filtrar la segunda variable de la division por sexo (la que puse más arriba), pero como filtro la primera parte por sexo?

Comment: podrias editar tu pregunta, usa el boton [edit], agrega ese codigo arriba, y explica que estas buscando. Pon ejemplos de ser necesario

Comment: No entiendo lo que pretendes conseguir. En preguntas de este tipo es buena idea incluir, además de una explicación lo más clara posible del resultado que se persigue, un pequeño ejemplo de los datos de entrada y la salida que se espera obtener con estos datos.